# How To Decode The Server Response of image String Uploaded through Base64?

Tags: android

I am uploading my image on server using Base64 as-

```
private String convertBitmapToString(ImageView imgview) {
    imgview.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap objbmap = imgview.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream objbitmapArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    objbmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, objbitmapArrayStream);
    byte[] objbitmaparray = objbitmapArrayStream.toByteArray();
    String img_string = Base64.encodeBytes(objbitmaparray);
    return img_string;
}
```

And When I want to Show That Image Hit Again Php Server Which give me response as-

```
     "picture":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT\/2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT\/wAARCABGAEcDASIAAhEBAxEB\/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQE"
```

I am unable to decode it please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

Well server gives you base64 encoded picture obviously, because online base64 decoder showed this when i decoded your string:

```
�JFIF�������C�
```

which is a sign of a correct image content, so just decode it.

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);
```

Comment: Hi,May I decode on UI Thread?and Is encodedBytes image String? thanks for hrlp